# use min_rf feature by pysolr package

Tags: solr, pysolr

I using **Pysolr** package in order send data to Apache Solr.
Apache Solr has one feature called *min_rf* ([Doc](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_4/solrcloud-recoveries-and-write-tolerance.html#achieved-replication-factor))

I used min_rf in my java code but Pysolr throws an error.

Do **Pysolr** package support this feature? How can I use this feature in code?

Comment: What have you tried in your pysolr code? What is the error? Is the error on the python side or on the Solr side?

Comment: Tanks @MatsLindh. actually I could not found any example or document that describe min_rf in Pysolr package. So I ask, Do Pysolr support this feature?because Pysolr throw exception this Error : TypeError: add() got an unexpected keyword argument 'min_rf'

Comment: Which version of Solr? As far as I can see, the `min_rf` parameter was deprecated in Solr 7.6 and the replication factor is now always returned, regardless of whether the parameter is present. However, I'm not sure if pysolr exposes that in any way..

Comment: @MatsLindh Yes min_df deprecated in 7.6 but I use Solr 7.4.
I could not find any example of min_rf in Pysolr package ! and I searched min_rf word in all code of this package but I could not found anything.

Comment: No, as far as I can see there is no option of including it in the request unless you modify pysolr yourself. You'd have to replace / monkey patch the `_update` method as far as I can see; not sure about how happy anything is going to be about those mangled names :-)